# In my rest webservice request for react using axios, the response json contains html div element. how can I get the value of this element?

Tags: reactjs

```
[
   {
      "title":"Palmeiras - Coritiba",
      "embed":"<div style='width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:calc(56.25% + 335px);' class='_scorebatEmbeddedPlayerW_'><iframe src='https://www.somestream.com/embed/g/934437/?s=2' frameborder='0' width='560' height='650' allowfullscreen allow='autoplay; fullscreen' style='width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;' class='_scorebatEmbeddedPlayer_'></iframe></div>",
      "url":"https://www.some.com/coritiba-vs-palmeiras-live-stream/",
      "thumbnail":"https://www.somestream.com/og/m/og934437.jpeg",
      "date":"2020-10-14T21:00:00+0000",
      "side1":{
         "name":"Palmeiras",
         "url":"https://www.some.com/live-stream/palmeiras/"
      },
      "side2":{
         "name":"Coritiba",
         "url":"https://www.some.com/live-stream/coritiba/"
      }
   }
]
```

I want to get the title, thumnail, and video, date feilds from this response but unable to get the video because it is in div element.

Comment: Can't see a div here.

Comment: You have to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for that but it comes with a security risk.

Comment: You need to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to read the HTML string into a JavaScript document.  The you can use DOM methods like querySelector and getElementById on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to read the HTML string into a JavaScript document. The you can use DOM methods like querySelector and getElementById on it.

Here's a function to return the video src from an HTML embed string.

```js
const getEmbedSrc = (embed) => {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(embed, "text/html");
  return doc.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src;
}

const embed = "<div style='width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:calc(56.25% + 335px);' class='_scorebatEmbeddedPlayerW_'><iframe src='https://www.somestream.com/embed/g/934437/?s=2' frameborder='0' width='560' height='650' allowfullscreen allow='autoplay; fullscreen' style='width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;' class='_scorebatEmbeddedPlayer_'></iframe></div>";

console.log(getEmbedSrc(embed));
```

Alternatively, you can find a match using regex.